# DPM 2007 SP1 agent Install on Microsoft HyperV server

Tags: hyper-v, scdpm

I have just setup an new server running Microsoft Hyper V Server (not windows server 2008 with Hyper V component). I am wanting to run a test to see if DPM 2007 SP1 can backup any VM's i create on the machine. I have currently got 1 windows server 2003 VM running on the Microsoft Hyper V Server.

To do this test i need to have an agent on the physical machine running Microsoft Hyper V Server. However, every time i try to install the agent from the DPM GUI i get  the following error:

Do the following to troubleshoot this issue:
1) Check the spelling of the computer name.
2) Verify that Windows Server 2003 with Service Pack 1 or later is installed on the computer.
3) Verify that you entered the fully qualified domain name for the computer.
4) If the computer has recently been added to the domain, you may need to wait for Active Directory to update.
5) If the computer was recently restarted, wait a few moments and then retry the agent operation again.
6) Verify that a two-way trust is enabled between the domain that the selected computer belongs to and the DPM server's domain.

ID: 322

I have the following KB/Hot Fixes installed on the server

```
   KB951636  
   KB956394                     
   KB957157_zh-TW               
   KB938464                     
   KB947864                     
   KB950050                     
   KB950974                     
   KB951978                     
   KB952004                     
   KB952287                     
   KB953733                     
   KB953838                    
   KB954459                     
   KB955069                     
   KB955302                     
   KB955306                     
   KB955430                    
   KB956386                     
   KB956393                     
   KB956572                     
   KB956802                     
   KB957097                    
   KB958623                     
   KB958644                     
   KB958687                     
   KB959426                     
   KB959962                     
   KB960225                     
   KB960803                     
   KB967902                     
   KB968389                     
   KB968537                     
   KB970238                     
   KB971657                     
   KB973507
```

I have already tried the following manual process and had the same error message come back in the command prompt :http://www.eggheadcafe.com/conversation.aspx?messageid=33588713&threadid=33588685

What do i need to do to get an agent installed on the Microsoft Hyperv Server?

Has anyone else been able to get DPM working with Microsoft HyperV Server?

Thanks in advance

-Matt

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing the problem because the Hyper-V HyperVisor uses Server Core 2008 and therefore cannot have any installers running directly as it has no GUI component. If you are installing using an MSI you can try and run the installer using the NOGUI switch.

Alternatively you need to contact the supplier for a version of the agent that can run on Server Core 2008, which is the same OS used by the HyperVisor.

I would recommend reading [this](http://www.petri.co.il/understanding-windows-server-2008-core.htm) article to get an overall understading of Server Core 2008 and the limitations within it.

I manage 2 of these servers and they are stable and very effective at what they do, but limited when it comes to external tools. We ended up loading the backup software onto each vritual machine and treat them like physical machines. We also moved the VM's to a SAN for DR purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your response. 

I have been able to install the DPM Agent onto 3 other a server core 2008 machines with little to no problems once you have the correct KB articles installed. 

This is the free Microsoft HyperV server that is meant to be usable by DPM 2007 SP1: See here for reference: http://blogs.technet.com/dpm/archive/2008/12/19/service-pack-1-for-dpm-2007-is-now-available.aspx

You are meant to be able to use DPM to backup the full VM if the agent is on the physical machine not just the files if the agent is on the vm.

- Matt

Comment: Matt. Fair comment. The free Hyper-V server is what I refer to and it uses Server Core Standard 2008. I am assuming the other 3 servers are the same. However they have severely crippled the Hyper Visor to avoid abuse.